# Factor a simple linear differential operator

Tags: derivatives, operator-algebras

Let $\frac{d}{dx}=D$, one of my exercises shows that the operator $(D^2-1)$ of a function $f(x)$ can be factor as either $(D-1)(D+1)$ or $(D+\tanh x)(D-\tanh x)$.

I understand the first factorization but do not get why it can be factorized as $(D-\tanh x)(D+\tanh x)$? My verification is as follows.

$$(D+\tanh x)(D-\tanh x)=D^2-D(\tanh x)+\tanh x * D-\tanh^2 x=D^2-(1-\tanh^2x)+\tanh x * D-\tanh^2 x=D^2-1+\color{red}{\tanh x*D}.$$

As you can see, there is an additional term (in red). Where I made a mistake?

Answer (score 2):

We assume $D:=\dfrac{d}{dx}$.

One may observe that
$$
\begin{align}
(D+\tanh )\circ(D-\tanh)\cdot f&=(D+\tanh )\circ\left(f'-\tanh \cdot f\right)
\\\\&=f''\color{blue}{-D (\tanh \cdot f)}+\tanh \cdot f'-\tanh^2 \cdot f
\\\\&=f''\color{blue}{-(1-\tanh^2) \cdot f-\tanh \cdot f'}+\tanh \cdot f'-\tanh^2 \cdot f
\\\\&=f''- f
\\\\&=(D^2-1)\cdot f
\end{align}
$$ as announced.

Comment: Thanks for your clear answer: the key point is that by including func $f$, one will note the chain rule involved in $D(\tanh x f)$. May I consult two further questions: (1) Will it be rigorously correct if we can add an independent var. in $\tanh$, that is, using $\tanh x$ instead of $\tanh$ only? (2) Is there any special meaning by $\circ$ apart from the meaning of multiplication? Thanks a lot.